# How can I keep a UISlider thumb small but with a higher res photo?

Tags: swift, uislider

[image: circle image][image]

I'm trying to adjust the size of a UISlider thumb. The only way I've come around is assigning it a custom image that's small. This works fine but the circle from the image being so small is really low res. How can I get the same effect as the UISlider in music with out making it look faded?

I have it set as a smaller image.

I have it setup through interface builder with a custom class.

```
@IBDesignable
class Slider_Design: UISlider {
    @IBInspectable var thumbImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            setThumbImage(thumbImage, for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the original image look like?

Comment: its just a small 20x20 circle. This was the only thing I could find to try. Anytime you add a larger icon to get the quality better the thumb gets larger @matt

Comment: Yes but what does this small 20x20 circle look like? What you are seeing is antialiasing. I'm trying to determine whether that is endemic to the image. Images that I use as slider thumbs look like the image.

Comment: @matt okay I edited my question and added the picture to it

Comment: Well, the image you added is very heavily antialiased around the outside. What you put in is what you get out. Open it with any image editor and zoom it and you can see that. So I can't figure out what the issue is; the image you are supplying is the image that is being drawn as the thumb. It seems to me that what you want is to start with a _large_ image and downsize it for use in the thumb.

Comment: @matt The issue is if I add a larger say 60x60 image the thumb becomes that size. I want to keep the thumb around 20x20 but I can't find a way to use say a 60x60 image to do it

Comment: Right, I'm saying supply a 60x60 image and reduce it to 20x20 in code before you hand it to the slider. That way if there is any antialiasing it will be mostly taken out due the increased sharpness as you size down. (Or use a vector-based image, which will be supersharp at any size, and size _that_ down.) Plus when you do that, you get to supply a scale factor matching the screen resolution, so it will look great on double and triple resolution devices.

Comment: @matt Thats what I was trying to do originally but I can't find any way to adjust the thumb size in code

Comment: OK, so _that_ is the question? How to downsize an image in code?

Comment: @matt yes if thats possible

Comment: Of course it's possible. It's an essential iOS programming technique. It's what you should _always_ do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that your question is actually something like: I've got a larger UIImage (say, 60x60) and I'd like to resize / reduce / downsize it to a smaller image (say, 20x20).

That would be something like this:

```
let sz = CGSize(width:20, height:20)
let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:sz)
let reducedImage = r.image { _ in
    UIImage(named:"whatever")?.draw(in:CGRect(origin:.zero, size:sz))
}
```